# Data Binding and User Controls-Updated for UWP, Windows 10 and instantiating via c# not XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I had to leave my Sr Developer job over 2 years ago due to a stroke, most of which was database work.

I am trying to see what if anything I remember about UI. Assuming C#, UWP, VS2017 and Windows 10 I have found some custom/user control samples that work but each one shows how to create the control and then use one instance of it in a main/parent app via XAML:

```
 <local:GamePiece x:Name="gp01"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="48" FontFamily="Wingdings" Margin="0,1,0,0"/>
```

But I want to create it programmatically:
e.g. `MyControl1 muc1 = new MyControl1()`

Such that the control has one textBlock control and two public properties (one will allow get/set of the text and another will allow get/set of the COLOR of said text (I would prefer to set the values of the properties via the constructor call from the main app e.g. `MyControl1 muc1 = new MyControl1(sDisplayText, Color.Red)` as in:

```
namespace ColorsAndShapes
{
    public sealed partial class GamePiece : UserControl
    {
        public GamePiece()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string sShape
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(sShapeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(sShapeProperty, value); }
        } 

        public static readonly DependencyProperty sShapeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("sShape", typeof(string), typeof(GamePiece), null);

        public Color cColor
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(cColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(cColorProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty cColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("cColor", typeof(Colors), typeof(GamePiece), null);

    }
}
```

This "works" for `sShape` but not for `cColor`, and it only works for `sShape` if I create the user control in the main app XAML, it does nothing if I try to do it programmatically (but once created via XAML I can then access the `sShape` property from the main app, but attempting to set a new color programmatically does not change the color nor does it throw an exception.

What am I missing?

There could be hundreds of these in the main app, so putting them in XAML doesn't make sense. Thank you.

Comment: I think you can use `MyControl1 muc1 = new MyControl1(){sShape="123",cColor=Color.Red}`

Comment: I don't think he's asking how to instantiate his control after writing a constructor for it.

Answer (score 0):

First off you have "typeof(Colors)" which I believe should be "typeof(Color)".  Colors is an enum of type Color, not the type itself.

Other than that your custom control looks fine.  You haven't shown us what you've done to create it programatically.  My suspicion is that you aren't adding it to the visual tree after instantiating it and setting all the values.

So identify a container control in XAML:

```
<Grid Name=GameBoard />
```

Then you can add instances of your control as children of the grid:

```
GameBoard.Children.Add(myGamePiece);
```

Also how are you checking if the color works?  Are you using it to create a SolidColorBrush?

Comment: I dont think he asks this

Comment: Well how else would you explain his control only works when created in XAML, and why the cColor property doesn't work regardless?  What do you think he's asking?

Comment: I can not know exactly what he means

Comment: Thank you to everyone who looked at this and responded. And sorry I couldn't reply before now. YES, I was asking for detail and I will try each of the suggestions. And THANK YOU! Each of you made comments that l believe will help. I think my skills are a bit outdated and my syntax was off in creating the instance, even though I tried overloading the constructors such that I could create the object via the constructor or alter it after it was created. And for the life of me .... Gameboard.Children.Add (must be getting senile).